# Stata: Combining multiple estpost results

Tags: stata

I am trying to combine the cumpct results I get from estpost tabulate with the summary statistics that I obtain from estpost tabstat in one esttab output.  However, I get a blank cumpct column by using the code below. I believe that the problem stems from the way I store the cumpct matrix but I, unfortunately, couldn't find a solution.

```
clear
input float A wage
1 100
3 450
2 180
2 190
1  70
4 880
3  65
5  40
1  144
4  28
5  110
end



     * tabulation
        estpost tabulate A
        matrix cumpct=e(cumpct)

     * Summary Stats
        estpost tabstat wage, ///
        statistics(mean sd p25 p50 p75) ///
        columns(statistics) by(A) 

     * Esttab
        esttab ., replace  ///
        cells("cumpct mean sd p25 p50 p75")
```

Result I get is the following:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                                                                 
                                                                                          
                   cumpct         mean           sd          p25          p50          p75
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                             104.6667     37.22007           70          100          144
2                                  185     7.071068          180          185          190
3                                257.5     272.2361           65        257.5          450
4                                  454      602.455           28          454          880
5                                   75     49.49747           40           75          110
Total                         205.1818     252.3192           65          110          190
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N                      11                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.
```

Comment: On Feb 27 you promised "I'll add a sample data set and my attempted code from now on!"

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I edited my question and added a sample data above

Comment: Thanks. I don't use this suite of commands, but you've made your question better for people who do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example after running:

```
estpost tabstat wage, ///
        statistics(mean sd p25 p50 p75) ///
        columns(statistics) by(A)
```

What is stored in e() is:

```
. ereturn list

scalars:
                  e(N) =  11

macros:
                e(cmd) : "estpost"
             e(subcmd) : "tabstat"
              e(stats) : "mean sd p25 p50 p75"
               e(vars) : "wage"
              e(byvar) : "A"

matrices:
               e(mean) :  1 x 6
                 e(sd) :  1 x 6
                e(p25) :  1 x 6
                e(p50) :  1 x 6
                e(p75) :  1 x 6
```

So when you run

```
esttab ., replace  ///
        cells("cumpct mean sd p25 p50 p75")
```

cumpct is not found and hence will be missing.

It is possible to manually add the cumulative matrix to e() with a small helper program.

```
clear
input float A wage
1 100
3 450
2 180
2 190
1  70
4 880
3  65
5  40
1  144
4  28
5  110
end

// Helper program
cap program drop add_e
program add_e, eclass
    args name matrix
    ereturn matrix `name' = `matrix'
end

* tabulation
estpost tabulate A
matrix cumpct=e(cumpct)

* Summary Stats
estpost tabstat wage, ///
statistics(mean sd p25 p50 p75) ///
columns(statistics) by(A) 

add_e "cumpct" cumpct

* Esttab
esttab ., replace  ///
cells("cumpct mean sd p25 p50 p75")
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                      (1)                                                                 
                                                                                          
                   cumpct         mean           sd          p25          p50          p75
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                27.27273     104.6667     37.22007           70          100          144
2                45.45455          185     7.071068          180          185          190
3                63.63636        257.5     272.2361           65        257.5          450
4                81.81818          454      602.455           28          454          880
5                     100           75     49.49747           40           75          110
Total                         205.1818     252.3192           65          110          190
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N                      11                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```